# Записать массив случайных чисел

Tags: java

А как сохранить массив сгенерированных чисел? Имеется в виду один раз сгенерировать и работать с одним и тем же массивом?

Comment: Сгенерируйте массив, сохраните его в поле объекта и используйте его на всём протяжении жизни объекта. Или вообще статическим полем класса его сделайте, если объект создавать не нужно.

Comment: должели массивы оставаться при перезапуске программы?

Comment: Да, должен.....

Comment: Тогда сохраняйте его куда-нибудь (например, в файл) и считывайте оттуда при запуске приложения.

Comment: @Regent а если сделать через new Random(10), разве не будет каждый раз при запуске программы одна и та же последовательность даваться? Должна же...

Comment: @Regent хм, я проверил это... на 3-х компах - приложение генерило одинаковые последовательности... потом почитал документацию))
В итоге конструктор с параметром, как в документации, создаёт одну и ту же цепочку псч, что логично. Ну да бог с ним)  
     Random random = new Random(10);
     String result = "";
     for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      result += random.nextInt(10) + " ";
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, result);

Comment: @Артём-.....-...-.- пардон, я провтыкал тот момент, что вы передаёте seed в конструктор. При таком подходе с тем же успехом можно просто жестко задать массив чисел в коде.

Answer (score 1):

Для сохранения вы можете использовать **ObjectOutputStream**

```
int[] a = new int[100]; //массив нужно заполнить

try (ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("./array"))) {
    out.writeObject(a);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Для считывания **ObjectInputStream**

```
int[] a = null;
try (ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("./array"))) {
    a = (int[]) in.readObject();
} catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, получилось.
int arraySize = 20;

// создаём массив

int[] randomArray = new int[arraySize];

// заполняем его случайными числами

for (int i = 0; i < randomArray.length; i++)

randomArray[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100);

//пишем в файл randomArray.bin

try {

OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("./randomArray.bin");

for(int i = 0 ; i < randomArray.length; i++)

outputStream.write(randomArray[i]);

}

catch (Exception e)

{

System.out.println("Не удалось созранить файл!");

// контрольная печать

System.out.println("Массив randomArray:");

printArray(randomArray);

// создаём другой массив

int[] anotherArray = new int[arraySize];

// считываем из файла randomArray.bin

try {

InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("./randomArray.bin");

for (int i = 0; i < anotherArray.length; i++)

anotherArray[i] = inputStream.read();

}

catch (Exception e){

System.out.println("Не удалось открыть файл!");

}

// контрольная печать

System.out.println("Массив anotherArray:");

printArray(anotherArray);

}

// фунция печатаем массив в одну строку

private static void printArray(int[] array)
 {

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)

System.out.print(array[i] + " "); 
System.out.println();

}